# Hibernate: map columns to fixed size map

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an entity object representing a game of 4 players each sitting on their table side, one of **N**, **E**, **S** or **W**. Games are stored in the database like this:

```
CREATE TABLE game_slot (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  ...
  player_N VARCHAR(127) NOT NULL,
  player_E VARCHAR(127) NOT NULL,
  player_S VARCHAR(127) NOT NULL,
  player_W VARCHAR(127) NOT NULL,
  ...
);
```

Each column is declared **NOT NULL** - there are always 4 players.

However, instead of 4 plain fields, I want `GameSlot` object to have single `players` field holding map with exactly 4 entries.

```
public class GameSlot {
  private int id;
  private Map<String, String> players = new HashMap<>();
  ...
}
```

Currently I implemented this by adding delegating virtual properties for each mapped table column:

```
  ...
  @JsonIgnore public String getPlayerN() { return this.players.get("N"); }
  @JsonIgnore public String getPlayerE() { return this.players.get("E"); }
  @JsonIgnore public String getPlayerS() { return this.players.get("S"); }
  @JsonIgnore public String getPlayerW() { return this.players.get("W"); }

  public void setPlayerN(String value) { this.players.put("N", value); }
  public void setPlayerE(String value) { this.players.put("E", value); }
  public void setPlayerS(String value) { this.players.put("S", value); }
  public void setPlayerW(String value) { this.players.put("W", value); }
  ...
```

With xml mappings it is straightforward:

```
<!-- GameSlot.hbm.xml -->
  ...
  <property name="playerN" column="player_N" not-null="true" length="127" />
  <property name="playerE" column="player_E" not-null="true" length="127" />
  <property name="playerS" column="player_S" not-null="true" length="127" />
  <property name="playerW" column="player_W" not-null="true" length="127" />
  ...
```

However, this approach seems awkward and I'd like to found better solution. So, **how can I map several table columns into single map**? Some conditions that are in play:

1. There is fixed number of affected columns - exactly and always 4
2. Each column is **NOT NULL**
3. Property | column types are all the same - `String` | `varchar(127)`
4. Keys to be used are known, fixed and all of same type
5. I'd rather use xml mappings, but annotations are also ok.